How to deploy a model from modeler to platform?
I am exploring Camunda BPMN.
I have downloaded modeler 5.30.0 and platform 8.6.5.
I launched c8run, and it opened a tab in browser at url 'http://localhost:8080/operate'.

In modeler, I created a simple flow:

But I am not sure how to now deploy it on platform. When I click deploy button in modeler, and provide details, I see error:

Shouldn't zeebee cluster be running within platform which I have already launched using c8run? I am not sure how to look into zeebee. In several you tube videos I see rest api being used to connect deploy on platform from modeler. But I don't see any such option in my modeler. It seems pretty daunting to deploy.

Looks like, you need to specify different Cluster Endpoint: it should be the local Zeeby URL, probably http://localhost:26500
